# Getting content from JSON string

Tags: java, android, json

I am currently developing an Android application which has a web backend. I can receive a JSON file which looks like the following:

```
[{"Latitude":"53.4041999","lontitude":"-6.377542"}]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the two coordinates from the JSON files and use them for mapping positions. Does anyone have any ideas how to get the two coordinates from the JSON file as `double`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
double lat = jObject.getDouble("Latitude");
double lng = jObject.getDouble("lontitude");
```

What you need to do is create `JSONObject` and just get double values using `getDouble(name);`

Edit: Either create JSONArray(see @Glenn.nz comment below) or just do `JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response.substring(1, response.lenth()-1));`

Comment: another note, if the JSON is specified exactly like you wrote, then youll need to get it as a JSONArray first and retrieve the first element in the array to knock off the [ ] and just get the JSONObject inside { }

Comment: hey guys cheers for the help I tried do it the way nikola said, but when I implemented it, my app said that Latitude doesnt have a value, cause this be down to my JSON file ?

Comment: Make sure the key-names are identical from the code and JSON file. Log the JSON data string before you do anything to have a grasp of whats going on ;) cheers

Comment: I have the Json file like the following:{"posts":[{"Latitude":"53.4041999","lontitude":"-6.377542"}]}, I can return it as a String by doing JSONObject ob= new JSONObject(s);
 String lngg = ob.getString("posts");,  but if I try get lontitude or Latitude I get the error saying no value for lontitude, and the same error for latitude. When I return it has a string it returns {"Latitude":"53.4041999","lontitude":"-6.377542"} and also if I return the 1st element of the array I get the same result

Comment: `JSONObject o = new JSONObject(thestring);
JSONArray a = o.getJSONArray("posts");
o = a.getJSONObject(0);
double lat = o.getDouble("Latitude");
double lng = o.getDouble("lontitude");`

Comment: That worked a treat thanks very much Nikola much appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 0):

+1 @Nikola's answer will work well, if you ensure that your json data structured as below

```
{"latitude": 53.4041999,"lontitude": -6.377542}
```